# Passing params in ES6 (React), SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to build a react component that generates a table. It calls a rails api to get its data. Data arrives at this component as an array of hashes.

On line 13 below I get 'SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token'.

I want to move the logic for creating a row to a method (makeRow). I am missing something obvious. I can access the hashes just fine, display them in a table row, but I can't figure out how to pass the hash to the makeRow method. As indicated by the comment in the code, it throws a syntax error on  line 13.

```
class ProductsTable extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    if (this.props.data){
        let rows = [];
      //debugger
      for ( var i =0; i < this.props.data.length; i++){
        //debugger
        //this.props.data[i] = {id: 5, name: "Enfield", description: "Bullet 500", price: "$5000005"}
        rows.push(<tr>{< this.makeRow(this.props.data[i]) />}</tr>)
        //                           ^ SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token
      }
      return (
          <div>
          <table id="product-table">
              <tbody>
              { rows }
            </tbody>
          </table>          
          </div>
    )} else {return(null)};
  }

  makeRow(row){
    //debugger
    return (<td> row.name </td>);
  }

}
```

Comment: In this line: `<tr>{< this.makeRow(this.props.data[i]) />}</tr>` you shouldn't have angle brackets around `this.makeRow(...)`. It should just be `<tr>{this.makeRow(this.props.data[i])}</tr>`

Comment: Also remember that for an array of elements/components, each element/component should be given a unique `key` prop. If you don't React will warn you about it (console error), as it can cause bugs and weird behaviour.

Comment: Oh and also, in your `makeRow()` function, you're missing curly braces around the variable embedded in the JSX. It should be: `return (<td> {row.name} </td>);`

Comment: This fixed it perfectly! Thank you. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angle bracket is reserved for component only. If we have any component, we should use `<MyComponent />`. For JavaScript inside jsx, we have to use plain JavaScript logic by enclosing curly bracket only. `<MyComponent>{this.state.name}</MyComonent>`